# OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (query.type() == type && indices.type() == CV_32S && dists.type() == dtype)

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to create a Bag-Of-Words with OpenCV, which I'm gonna use later to train SVM. Unfortunately my program does not work.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <dirent.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int check_num = 0;

    Mat featuresUnclustered;

    Ptr<DescriptorMatcher> matcher = DescriptorMatcher::create("FlannBased");
    Ptr<DescriptorExtractor> extractor = DescriptorExtractor::create("BRIEF");
    Ptr<FeatureDetector> detector = FeatureDetector::create("FAST");


    Mat img = imread("./positive_images/1.jpg");

    vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;
    detector->detect(img,keypoints);

    extractor->compute(img, keypoints, featuresUnclustered);
    featuresUnclustered.convertTo(featuresUnclustered, CV_32F);

    int dictionarySize = 1000;
    TermCriteria tc(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER,100,0.001);
    int retries = 1;
    int flags = KMEANS_PP_CENTERS;

    BOWKMeansTrainer bowTrainer(dictionarySize,tc,retries,flags);

    cout << "check: " << check_num << endl;
    check_num++;

    Mat dictionary = bowTrainer.cluster(featuresUnclustered);

    cout << "check: " << check_num << endl;
    check_num++;

    BOWImgDescriptorExtractor bowDE(extractor,matcher);
    bowDE.setVocabulary(dictionary);

    cout << "check: " << check_num << endl;
    check_num++;

    Mat bowDescriptor;
    bowDE.compute(img,keypoints,bowDescriptor);

    cout << "check: " << check_num << endl;
    check_num++;

    return 0;
}
```

The last check is not printed, so this means the problem is with bowDE.compute(); but I don't know what it is caused by. This is the error given:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (query.type() == type && indices.type() == CV_32S && dists.type() == dtype) in runKnnSearch_, file /build/buildd/opencv-2.4.8+dfsg1/modules/flann/src/miniflann.cpp, line 469
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /build/buildd/opencv-2.4.8+dfsg1/modules/flann/src/miniflann.cpp:469: error: (-215) query.type() == type && indices.type() == CV_32S && dists.type() == dtype in function runKnnSearch_

Aborted (core dumped)
```

I'm doing this for the first time so it is difficult for me to fix it. Can you tell what the problem is? Thank you in advance!

Comment: you *can't* use BOW with binary descriptors like brief, only sift and surf allowed.

Comment: Isn't there any other descriptor to use? I don't want to use surf because it is a non-free algorithm.

Comment: then you just can't use BOW. period. (it's not only the float/byte descriptors issue, bow works using kmeans, and that only makes sense with data, that plays nice with L2 distance)

Comment: Then what should I use to train the SVM?

Comment: maybe you can checkout some altrnative keypoint-detectors, that give you a lot of keypoints(more than you need), and retain only  those with the highest response value (a fixed count, since all your svm vecs need to be same length). but again, a SVM is just a 'glorified L2 norm',  so,  bad for any binary descriptors.